# "git show" command showing previous commit

Tags: git, git-show

I'm trying to show the contents of a file in a specific commit,
this is the command I'm using:

```
git show ($commit)^:($filename)
```

However, it's showing contents of the previous commit.
I'm not sure if this command is supposed to get the contents "before" the commit,
or if it's because the commit I specified was for reverting the previous commit.

Comment: Do you want to see the diff of the file for that particular commit?

Comment: Nope, just want to see what the file looks like after that commit was pushed in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^` operator means "the ancestor of the given commit". Just remove it, and you should be fine:

```
$ git show ($commit):($filename)
```

Comment: One side note: it's a *suffix* hat `^` (followed by an optional number, default `1`) that means "parent". A prefix `^` here is invalid but in other contexts, the prefix hat operator means "not".